# Why can't MySQL use an index for ORDER BY if ASC and DESC are mixed?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

Let's say I have a very simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `key_part1` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `key_part2` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `value` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key_part1`, `key_part2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Using this table, I want to issue a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `t1`
ORDER BY `key_part1` ASC, `key_part2` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I had hoped that the `ORDER BY` in this query would get satisfied by the index.  However, according to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html):

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the `ORDER BY`, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the `WHERE` clause. These cases include the following:
>
> - You mix `ASC` and `DESC`:
>
> `SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 ASC;`

I tried a query similar to the above query and as expected, the `EXPLAIN` output says that such a query does a filesort.  This doesn't totally make sense to me because I can do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM `t1`
WHERE `key_part1` = (
    SELECT `key_part1`
    FROM `t1`
    ORDER BY `key_part1` ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY `key_part2` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

When I `EXPLAIN` this, it says both the subquery and the outer query do not use a filesort.  Furthermore, I tried this kind of trick big table I have with a similar structure and found that it speeds up my query by 3 orders of magnitude.

My questions are

1. Are the two queries I show here equivalent?  They seem like they are, but I may be missing something.  If they are not, what kind of data would I need to have in my table to cause them to give different results?
2. Is there a reason that MySQL can't do this optimization trick on it's own, or is this just a case of an optimization that is possible, but just hasn't been written into MySQL?

If it matters, I am using MySQL 5.6.22.

*Further clarification:*

By "equivalent" I mean "produce the same result".  Additionally, I am very aware that if I were to change `LIMIT 1` to `LIMIT 2` or something, the queries would no longer produce the same results. *I am not interested in those cases, only in the case with `LIMIT 1`.*

Comment: I'm relatively certain MySQL stores the indexes in ascending order, so you can't read it in both directions at once.  A trick you could use would be to specify a third column, that is the negation of key_part2 (ie, -1 * key_part2), create your compound index on that, and sort by both values ascending.  [doc ref here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html), about a third of the way down.

Comment: What are the `key_parts`?  I ask because the semantics of the columns can provide an alternative solution.

Comment: The specific case of this problem I had to deal with had `key_part1` as an enum  with only a few values and `key_part2` is an foreign key from another table.

Comment: You have a where clause in the 2nd query and not the first.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that MySQL is missing an optimization "trick", it's a property of how compound indexes work. MySQL can only do an index scan in one direction at a time, and has to go with how the index is ordered (so it can do computer-sciency things like binary search, etc).

Let's look at your sample query:

SELECT *
FROM `t1`
WHERE `key_part1` = (
    SELECT `key_part1`
    FROM `t1`
    ORDER BY `key_part1` ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY `key_part2` DESC
LIMIT 1

This can order on key_part2 because all returned rows will have an identical key_part1. So basically mysql can ignore that part of the index; it is functionally identical to `ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 DESC`. The direction of the `ORDER BY` in your subquery is irrelevant because it was in a subquery.

*Edit*

To be clear, your example query really looks like this:

SELECT *
FROM `t1`
WHERE `key_part1` = #{some value}
ORDER BY `key_part2` DESC
LIMIT 1

Where `#{some value}` is the result of a subselect. It should be clear now why this sort doesn't need a filesort, because you are not sorting by `key_part1` at all. In fact, there is no need to, because all returned rows will have identical `key_part1`.

Comment: "The direction of the ORDER BY in your subquery is irrelevant because it was in a subquery." This is not true; I just tried it (MySQL 5.5).  If I change `ASC` to `DESC` in the subquery, I get a different result.

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear. I think you are asking "why can I order by key_part2 DESC without filesort even though my subquery orders by key_part1 ASC?" 

It is irrelevant in the sense that the subquery doesn't affect the query plan for the outer query. But I did not mean to say that it won't affect the returned results.

Comment: Oh ok, yes that's true, and I understand why no filesort is done.  Really what I am asking is why MySQL can't avoid doing a filesort in my original query; shouldn't it be smart enough to realize that it can convert the original query into a version that uses a subquery to avoid doing a filesort?

Comment: The two queries in your example are not equivalent. Query #1 has no WHERE clause, therefore it can have more than one `key_part1`, so cannot be converted to an equivalent subquery.

Imagine someone hands you a dictionary: "give me all words that start with 'a' sorted by the first 2 characters" - that's easy. Now try "give me all the words that start with 'a' sorted by the first 2 characters, but if there's a tie, sort it by the 3rd character in reverse." There is no way to do that without a second pass (a filesort), but that's essentially what you're asking for.

Comment: And Query #2 is approximately:

subquery: "get me all words that start with these 2 letters"
outer query: "sort the subquery's results by the third letter in reverse" (equivalent to "sort the subquery's results by the first 3 letters in reverse" because all the results have identical first and second letters)

Comment: "Query #1 has no WHERE clause, therefore it can have more than one key_part1" This is false; there's a `LIMIT 1` on the end, so no matter what data I have, I won't be dealing with more than one value of `key_part1`.  If you really think the two queries are different, can you suggest test data I could use that would cause the two queries to give different results?

Comment: A LIMIT clause is not the same as a WHERE clause. LIMIT doesn't narrow down the search space, it just truncates the results. If you were to try LIMIT 2 then you could get different results.

And at this point you've edited the question to move the goalposts - you are asking whether the two queries give identical results  - given the constraints, they do. But that isn't the same as asking whether the two queries are identical  - they aren't, because your second query is really two (much more efficient) queries, and cannot reliably return more than 1 result in that order.

Comment: "you are asking whether the two queries give identical results" That was always what I meant by "equivalent", sorry if it wasn't clear.  I am ONLY interested in the case where I need one result, you are surely correct that this trick won't work if I needed more than that.  You do seem to have answered my first question though, so thank you for that.